# Exception handled surprisingly in PyQt/Pyside slots

Tags: python, exception, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

**Problem:** When exceptions are raised in slots, invoked by signals, they do not seem to propagate as usual through *Pythons* call stack. In the example code below invoking:

- `on_raise_without_signal()`: Will handle the exception as expected.
- `on_raise_with_signal()`: Will print the exception and then unexpectedly print the success message from the `else` block.

**Question:** What is the reason behind the exception being handled surprisingly when raised in a slot? Is it some implementation detail/limitation of the *PySide* Qt wrapping of signals/slots? Is there something to read about in the docs?

**PS:** I initially came across that topic when I got surprising results upon using *try/except/else/finally* when implementing a `QAbstractTableModels` virtual methods `insertRows()` and `removeRows()`.

---

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Testing exception handling in PySide slots."""
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function, division

import logging
import sys

from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ExceptionTestWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    raise_exception = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExceptionTestWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.raise_exception.connect(self.slot_raise_exception)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # button to invoke handler that handles raised exception as expected
        btn_raise_without_signal = QtGui.QPushButton("Raise without signal")
        btn_raise_without_signal.clicked.connect(self.on_raise_without_signal)
        layout.addWidget(btn_raise_without_signal)

        # button to invoke handler that handles raised exception via signal unexpectedly
        btn_raise_with_signal = QtGui.QPushButton("Raise with signal")
        btn_raise_with_signal.clicked.connect(self.on_raise_with_signal)
        layout.addWidget(btn_raise_with_signal)

    def slot_raise_exception(self):
        raise ValueError("ValueError on purpose")

    def on_raise_without_signal(self):
        """Call function that raises exception directly."""
        try:
            self.slot_raise_exception()
        except ValueError as exception_instance:
            logger.error("{}".format(exception_instance))
        else:
            logger.info("on_raise_without_signal() executed successfully")

    def on_raise_with_signal(self):
        """Call slot that raises exception via signal."""
        try:
            self.raise_exception.emit()
        except ValueError as exception_instance:
            logger.error("{}".format(exception_instance))
        else:
            logger.info("on_raise_with_signal() executed successfully")


if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = ExceptionTestWidget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've already noted in your question, the real issue here is the treatment of unhandled exceptions raised in python code executed from C++. So this is not only about signals: it also affects reimplemented virtual methods as well.

In PySide, PyQt4, and all PyQt5 versions up to 5.5, the default behaviour is to automatically catch the error on the C++ side and dump a traceback to stderr. Normally, a python script would also automatically terminate after this. But that is not what happens here. Instead, the PySide/PyQt script just carries on regardless, and many people quite rightly regard this as a bug (or at least a misfeature). In PyQt-5.5, this behaviour has now been changed so that `qFatal()` is also called on the C++ side, and the program will abort like a normal python script would. (I don't know what the current situation is with PySide2, though).

So - what should be done about all this? The best solution for all versions of PySide and PyQt is to install an [exception hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?#sys.excepthook) - because it will always take precedence over the default behaviour (whatever that may be). Any unhandled exception raised by a signal, virtual method or other python code will firstly invoke `sys.excepthook`, allowing you to fully customise the behaviour in whatever way you like.

In your example script, this could simply mean adding something like this:

```
def excepthook(cls, exception, traceback):
    print('calling excepthook...')
    logger.error("{}".format(exception))

sys.excepthook = excepthook
```

and now the exception raised by `on_raise_with_signal` can be handled in the same way as all other unhandled exceptions.

Of course, this does imply that best practice for most PySide/PyQt applications is to use largely centralised exception handling. This often includes showing some kind of crash-dialog where the user can report unexpected errors.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Qt5 docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html) you need to handle exceptions within the slot being invoked.

> Throwing an exception from a slot invoked by Qt's signal-slot connection mechanism is considered undefined behaviour, unless it is handled within the slot

```
State state;
StateListener stateListener;

// OK; the exception is handled before it leaves the slot.
QObject::connect(&state, SIGNAL(stateChanged()), &stateListener, SLOT(throwHandledException()));
// Undefined behaviour; upon invocation of the slot, the exception will be propagated to the
// point of emission, unwinding the stack of the Qt code (which is not guaranteed to be exception safe).
QObject::connect(&state, SIGNAL(stateChanged()), &stateListener, SLOT(throwUnhandledException()));
```

> If the slot was invoked directly, like a regular function call,
>   exceptions may be used. This is because the connection mechanism is
>   bypassed when invoking slots directly

In the first case you call `slot_raise_exception()` directly, so this is fine.

In the second case you are invoking it via the `raise_exception` signal, so the exception will only propagate up to the point where `slot_raise_exception()` is called. You need to place the `try/except/else` inside `slot_raise_exception()` for the exception to be handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering guys. I found *ekhumoros* answer particularly useful to understand where the exceptions are handled and because of the idea to utilize `sys.excepthook`.

I mocked up a quick solution via context manager to temporarily extend the current `sys.excepthook` to record any exception in the realm of *"C++ calling Python"* (as it seems to happen when slots are invoked by signals or virtual methods) and possibly re-raise upon exiting the context to achieve expected control flow in *try/except/else/finally* blocks.

The context manager allows `on_raise_with_signal` to maintain the same control flow as `on_raise_without_signal` with the surrounding *try/except/else/finally* block.

---

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Testing exception handling in PySide slots."""
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function, division

import logging
import sys
from functools import wraps

from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class ExceptionHook(object):

    def extend_exception_hook(self, exception_hook):
        """Decorate sys.excepthook to store a record on the context manager
        instance that might be used upon leaving the context.
        """

        @wraps(exception_hook)
        def wrapped_exception_hook(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
            self.exc_val = exc_val
            return exception_hook(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)

        return wrapped_exception_hook

    def __enter__(self):
        """Temporary extend current exception hook."""
        self.current_exception_hook = sys.excepthook
        sys.excepthook = self.extend_exception_hook(sys.excepthook)

        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """Reset current exception hook and re-raise in Python call stack after
        we have left the realm of `C++ calling Python`.
        """
        sys.excepthook = self.current_exception_hook

        try:
            exception_type = type(self.exc_val)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            msg = "{}".format(self.exc_val)
            raise exception_type(msg)


class ExceptionTestWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    raise_exception = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExceptionTestWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.raise_exception.connect(self.slot_raise_exception)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # button to invoke handler that handles raised exception as expected
        btn_raise_without_signal = QtGui.QPushButton("Raise without signal")
        btn_raise_without_signal.clicked.connect(self.on_raise_without_signal)
        layout.addWidget(btn_raise_without_signal)

        # button to invoke handler that handles raised exception via signal unexpectedly
        btn_raise_with_signal = QtGui.QPushButton("Raise with signal")
        btn_raise_with_signal.clicked.connect(self.on_raise_with_signal)
        layout.addWidget(btn_raise_with_signal)

    def slot_raise_exception(self):
        raise ValueError("ValueError on purpose")

    def on_raise_without_signal(self):
        """Call function that raises exception directly."""
        try:
            self.slot_raise_exception()
        except ValueError as exception_instance:
            logger.error("{}".format(exception_instance))
        else:
            logger.info("on_raise_without_signal() executed successfully")

    def on_raise_with_signal(self):
        """Call slot that raises exception via signal."""
        try:
            with ExceptionHook() as exception_hook:
                self.raise_exception.emit()
        except ValueError as exception_instance:
            logger.error("{}".format(exception_instance))
        else:
            logger.info("on_raise_with_signal() executed successfully")


if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    application = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = ExceptionTestWidget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

This way of handling expcetions is not a surprise taking into consideration that the Signal/Slot architecture proposes a loosely coupled intercation between the signals and the slots. This means that the signal should not be expecting anything to happen inside the slots.

Although [timmwagener](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2889970/timmwagener)'s solution was pretty clever, it should be used with caution. Probably the problem is not with how Exceptions are handled between Qt Connections, but that the signal/slot architecture is not ideal for your application. Also, that solution would not work if a slot from a different thread is connected, or a Qt.QueuedConnection is used.

A good way of tackling the problem of errors raised in slots is to determine that at the connection and not the emitting. Then the erros can be handled in a loosely coupled way.

```
class ExceptionTestWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    error = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def abort_execution():
        pass

    def error_handler(self, err):
        self.error.emit(error)
        self.abort_execution()

(...)

def connect_with_async_error_handler(sig, slot, error_handler, *args,
                                     conn_type=None, **kwargs):                              

    @functools.wraps(slot)
    def slot_with_error_handler(*args):
        try:
            slot(*args)
        except Exception as err:
            error_handler(err)

    if conn_type is not None:
        sig.connect(slot_with_error_handler, conn_type)
    else:
        sig.connect(slot_with_error_handler)
```

This way, we would be complying to the requirements in the [Qt5 docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html), stating that you need to handle exceptions within the slot being invoked.

> Throwing an exception from a slot invoked by Qt's signal-slot
> connection mechanism is considered undefined behaviour, unless it is
> handled within the slot

**PS:** This is just a sugestion based on a very small overview of your use case. **There is no right/wrong way of solving this**, I just wanted to bring out a different point of view : )

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possible issue in my example with asynchronous code. I think that's right. However, i'm not sure if it's "officially undefined behaviour" to raise in slots in Qt's Python wrappers like PySide2 (Your example is from the C++ docs i guess). As @ekhumoro pointed out, it seems like an explicit effort has been made there, to include Pythons default root exception handling by calling `sys.excepthook` _(which has the defined behaviour to log the exception to stderr)_. Or could you find any link to PySide2 docs also stating that would be undefined?

Comment: Having the sys.excepthook attached comes in extremely handy when you are debugging complex asynchronous applications, and a signal that should be getting fired is not fired because an error was suppressed in a slot somewhere in the execution. That would be enough reason for this explicit effort. Besides, of course, the fact that PEP states that all uncaught exceptions should go through sys.excepthook. Thus more than enough reason for this explicit effort.
Also, Py QT is just a binding on top of C++ QT. So in my interpretation, if it is undefined behavior in C++ it is also undefined in Python.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong with this next comment, but I don't see a big point in using QT Signal/Slot mechanism if you are not going for an asynchronous application. There are simpler structures to be used in this case if the only benefit is the decoupling of the parts. Which brings me back to my first suggestion: Maybe the signal/slot architecture is not ideal for his application.

My general thumb rule is: If you need to start doing a lot of fancy and clever workarounds, you are probably following the wrong path, and need to rethink the architecture of your application.